# Pandas: DatetimeIndex loc not playing nice

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue with two DataFrames, "df" and "all_days".   My goal is to do:

```
all_days.loc[df.index,"Value"] = df["TargetCol"]
```

Both have DatetimeIndex:

```
df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-15',
               '2021-01-21', '2021-01-28', '2021-01-28', '2021-02-03',
               '2021-02-05', '2021-02-17',
               ...
               '2023-06-15', '2023-06-15', '2023-07-27', '2023-07-27',
               '2023-09-14', '2023-09-21', '2023-10-26', '2023-11-02',
               '2023-12-14', '2023-12-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='release_dates_&_times', length=181, freq=None)

all_days.index
DatetimeIndex(['2022-08-24', '2022-08-25', '2022-08-26', '2022-08-27',
               '2022-08-28', '2022-08-29', '2022-08-30', '2022-08-31',
               '2022-09-01', '2022-09-02',
               ...
               '2024-08-14', '2024-08-15', '2024-08-16', '2024-08-17',
               '2024-08-18', '2024-08-19', '2024-08-20', '2024-08-21',
               '2024-08-22', '2024-08-23'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=731, freq='D')
```

This throws the following error though:

```
KeyError: "[Timestamp('2021-01-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-01-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:00:00'), ..., Timestamp('2022-08-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-08-18 00:00:00')] not in index"
```

Comment: Not sure what else is expected. The given indexes (`df.index`) are not in `all_days.index`. You may want to do `df.index.intersection(all_days.index)`.

Comment: I'm simply trying to set a subset (df.index) of all_day values to values in df.   Using intersection simply returns df.index, as all of df.index exist in all_days.index

Comment: No it's not. From what you printed `all_days` seems to start from `2022-08-24` whereas `df` starts from `2021-01-06`. The errors listed up to `2022-08-18` as not available.

Comment: Wellll thats unexpected...

Comment: In that case, how would I still set values on the intersection?

Comment: Like I said, `df.index.intersection(...)` or you can also do `all_days.loc[all_days.index.isin(df.index),...]`